# While using Request Class for validation Laravel shows - The POST method is not supported

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-10

Error shows on postman: **The POST method is not supported for route /. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.**

The above error shows while I write the **loginAdmin** function with **LoginRequest** Validator. Otherwise if I use `Request $request` it works fine.

**AdminController:**

```
public function loginAdmin(LoginRequest $request) {
   return $this->authService->login($request);
}
```

**api.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function ($router) {
    Route::post('/register', [AdminController::class, 'registerAdmin']);
    Route::post('/login', [AdminController::class, 'loginAdmin']);
});
```

I appreciate any help !!

Comment: `php artisan route:list`-> check if is in the list the route.
`php artisan route:clear`-> check if isn't cache.
make sure to put `api/admin/login` because you inserted in `api.php`. PS: laravel 8 or 10? in tags*

Comment: Laravel 10.  It seems its working when I send json data instead of form data. But for the validation if I send correct data it works when I send data that fails the validation, instead of throwing error message the system breaks and says 500 internal server error.

Comment: it seems to be trying to POST to `/` instead of either of the routes you listed. Can you watch the Network tab to see if there's some sort of redirect going on, and make sure it's originally trying to submit to the correct URL?

Answer (score 0):

try to catch the error in the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file. I think this will give you more information

```
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{
    dd($e);
}
```